# SAS: how to move cell content from Var2 to Var1 if Var1 is empty

Tags: sas, do-while

First post on the forum! I'm an amateur sas user with very basic programming skills, and vocabulary sadly...

Here's the idea: for a single observation, I've got 6 variables. Lets call them Fonction1 to 6.

If Fonction1 is empty, I'd like sas to move the content from Fonction2 to Fonction1, from Fonction3 to Fonction2, etc... until it is not empty anymore

then if Fonction2 is empty, same goes.

so something like

Observation 1:   9, 9, BLANK, BLANK, 5, 4
would become
Observation 1:   9, 9, 5, 4, Blank, Blank

note that the whole observation could be empty and that would be fine

So I wrote the following code:

```
    data individus_fct; 
    set individus_fct;
    do while (Fonction1 = '' and n<8);
        put n=;
        n+1;
        Fonction1 = Fonction2;
        Fonction2 = Fonction3;
        Fonction3 = Fonction4;
        Fonction4 = Fonction5;
        Fonction5 = Fonction6;
        Fonction6 = '';
    end;
    run;
data individus_fct; 
set individus_fct;
    do while (Fonction2 = '' and n<8);
        put n=;
        n+1;
        Fonction2 = Fonction3;
        Fonction3 = Fonction4;
        Fonction4 = Fonction5;
        Fonction5 = Fonction6;
        Fonction6 = '';
    end;
    run;
data individus_fct; 
set individus_fct;
    do while (Fonction3 = '' and n<8);
        put n=;
        n+1;
        Fonction3 = Fonction4;
        Fonction4 = Fonction5;
        Fonction5 = Fonction6;
        Fonction6 = '';
    end;
    run;
data individus_fct; 
set individus_fct;
    do while (Fonction4 = '' and n<8);
        put n=;
        n+1;
        Fonction4 = Fonction5;
        Fonction5 = Fonction6;
        Fonction6 = '';
    end;
    run;
data individus_fct; 
set individus_fct;
    do while (Fonction5 = '' and n<8);
        put n=;
        n+1;
        Fonction5 = Fonction6;
        Fonction6 = '';
    end;
    run;
```

But it's not working... no idea why... (I'd love to know though!)

Any suggestions?

Comment: As comments to your original code: You don't need separate datasteps here.  You could have done all of this in a single datastep - just removing 'run', 'data', and 'set' statements would accomplish the same thing here.  I'm not sure what your n+1 is really doing, or why n<8 is on each statement; you're basically iterating through it 7 times sometimes, but you don't ever have 7 to iterate through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic concept here is a double array traversal.  This is not the single fastest way, but it's much easier than the slightly faster options.

```
data have;      *creating some random data;
array fonction[6];
do _t = 1 to 20;
do x = 1 to 6;
  if ranuni(7) < 0.7 then fonction[x]=x;  *70% chance we get a value;
end;
output;
call missing(of fonction:);          *clear out array for next time;
end;
run;

data want;
set have;
array vars fonction1-fonction6; *vars can be any name;
do _item = 1 to dim(vars); *_item is iterator, dim(vars) is count of items in vars array;
  _counter=_item+1;
  do while (missing(vars[_item]) and _counter le dim(vars)); *repeat until you get a nonmissing or you hit the last item of the array;
    vars[_item] = vars[_counter];  *make current value equal to the next value;
    vars[_counter]=.;      *set the next value to missing - it will be fixed later;
    _counter=_counter+1;   *increment iterator, or you have infinite loops!;
  end;
  if _counter > dim(vars) then leave;  *if we got to the end early, then we are done here;
end;
run;
```